# Run multiple test same build from different tests project

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, tfs, tfsbuild, vstest

Need your help in the following scenario:

- I have a solution with 2 projects with different unit tests
- Those projects generate 2 different dll: *deployment.dll and *database.dll
- I have a build on TFS that I want to use to run those tests, I'm using "Test Case Filter" to filter the categories of my tests

  ```
  (TestCategory=TEST1|TestCategory=TEST2|TestCategory=TEST3|TestCategory=TEST4)
  ```

  and in "Test Sources Spec" I'm filtering both dll (`*deployment.dll;*database.dll`)
- *.deployment.dll has TEST2, TEST3, TEST4
- *.database.dll has TEST1

This doesn't work, tests of *database.dll does not run. Test selected in Visual Studio Test Runner

Could you please help on that? If I make the build with only 1 dll, for example, *.database.dll, TEST1 runs well.

**(UPDATE) SCENARIO 1**

*Test Case Filter:* TestCategory=TEST1|TestCategory=TEST1|TestCategory=TEST2|TestCategory=TEST3|TestCategory=TEST4

*Test Sources Spec:* *database.dll;*deployment.dll

**only runs TEST1**

---

**(UPDATE) SCENARIO 2**

*Test Case Filter:* TestCategory=TEST1|TestCategory=TEST1|TestCategory=TEST2|TestCategory=TEST3|TestCategory=TEST4

*Test Sources Spec:* **\*deployment.dll;*database.dll

**only runs TEST2,TEST3,TEST4**

**(UPDATE) Does not find tests in Database.dll**
[image]

Comment: With no filters applied, but adding both assemblies, do the tests run? What is the implementation technology of these tests, mstest? What version of TFS? What version of VS? (please adjust the tags to be more precise). How are the categories applied? At the test level? Class Level? Namespace level?

Comment: Which build system are you using? XAML or the new TFS 2015/2017 type builds?

Comment: Assuming you are using XAML build, I couldn't reproduce your issue on my side. You may check the questions of jessehouwing and provide more details.

Comment: I need this filters to make sure tests has a specific sort, do you know some another way to do that?
VS 2015 Update 3
XAML build
Categories applied at test level

The example below from Cece it's my scenario, but I have more tests in each project

Comment: @Cece-MSFT , Visual Studio Test Runner

Comment: @jessehouwing , Visual Studio Test Runner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it's solved :)

So, what I have done to solve this problem, was, change Build Process Template.

There are one step in this process, calling: "FindMatchingFiles"

I change this value as the below image shows. (however, from now on, I must use "**\*" in all my filters that use this process template). This operation make sure that I have the assemblies with fullpath destination complete.

If you have different solutions, please post here :)

**Special thank you to @Cece - MSFT for all support**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've tested in TFS 2015.3, XAML build, but couldn't reproduce your issue. I'd like to share my steps here for your reference:

1. I have a solution with some projects, 2 of them are UnitTest projects (UnitTestProject1, UnitTestProject2).

   [image]
2. In UnitTest1 project, I added TestCategory for two test case, check screenshot below:

   ```
   [TestMethod()]
   [TestCategory("Pro")]
   public void M1Test()
   {
      //
   }

   [TestMethod()]
   [TestCategory("Dev")]
   public void M2Test()
   {
       //
   }
   ```
3. Similar to Step2, in UnitTest2 project, I added TestCategory for two test case, check screenshot below:

   ```
   [TestMethod()]
   [TestCategory("Pro1")]
   public void M3Test()
   {
      //
   }

   [TestMethod()]
   [TestCategory("Dev1")]
   public void M4Test()
   {
       //
   }
   ```
4. Edit "Test Case Filter" and "Test Sources Spec" in build definition like below screenshot and queue a build:

[image]

5. The test result is as expected. Only M1Test and M2Test in UnitTestProject1, M3Test and M4Test in UnitTestProject2 are tested.

Comment: Hi Cece, I made has you suggest, initialy I had **\*database.dll;**\*deployment, I change to *database.ddl;*deployment.dll and now, the TEST1 runs well, the other tests doesn't run.
I change to *database.dll;**\*deployment.dll and gives me an error:
Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.IE5' is denied

Do you have any idea what happens?

Comment: What's the full name of *deployment.dll, and *database.dll? How about **\ *deployment.dll;**\ *database.dll?

Comment: Hermes.Gold.Deployment.dll
Hermes.Gold.Database.dll

Could this be an error on process template? Because it seems only catch one of the assemblies that I insert in Test Sources Spec...

How works the foreach to the TestSpecList?

Comment: Hi already look at the process template, and it seems all ok, however, the content of MatchPattern is this: "String.Format("{0}\{1}", BuildDetail.DropLocation, agileTestPlatformAssembly.AssemblyFileSpec)", and it seems not catch the tests of all sources, notice this message (updated in this topic):
**There are no matches for the search pattern **\\*Database.dll**

Comment: With no filters applied, but adding both assemblies, do the tests run?

Comment: No test results found, the status bar of build is "Orange" and it gives this error again:

_Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.IE5' is denied._

Comment: The access to the path is denied I already solved (gave permission to INetCache to everyone), but still missing to find tests on *Database*.dll